# Cycle through a set of multiple images with jquery in an endless loop?

Tags: jquery, image, caching, cycle

I have this jquery image cycler that does the following:

- preload multiple images ( say 50? )
- Pick random from these 40 and assign 14 of them to 14 div's each time
- cycling them forever

**What would be the best way to cycle through 14 images, getting a random image assigned to each of the 14 divs?**

EDIT:
AJAX calls like my first solution seems a stupid idea ( high load on server if there are hundreds of pages open ) so precaching seems a better option.

EDIT2:
Rewrote the question to be more precise and clear

I found this great method on pre-caching:

```
  var images = [
    '/path/to/image1.png',
    '/path/to/image2.png'
];

$(images).each(function() {
    var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
});
```

My old current method:

```
  $("#hi1").load('/get_img');
  $("#hi2").load('/get_img');
  $("#hi3").load('/get_img');
  ... etc till 14

  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#h1").load('/get_img');
      $("#h2").load('/get_img');
      $("#h3").load('/get_img');
      }, 4000);
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  })
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'cycling them forever'? that somehow contradicts loading new images every 4 seconds.

Comment: Are there 14 total images, or does `/get_img` return a new random image from a large pool?

Comment: @CWSpear Yes there are 14 images returned from a larger-pool by the get_image function

Comment: @Dominik A bit unclear on my part: I ment loading in multiple images and then cycling them every 4 seconds, where each of them would be replaced by a new one ( not shown before )

Comment: you don't need Ajax for this. Just reset the src attribute of your images ever 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return the source in the AJAX and create an `<img>` and set the src, and then if it's not needed, hide it, so if that image gets returned again, you can just unhide it instead of loading it again. You can check to see if the image exists with something like:

```
$('img[src="' + src + '"]').length > 0;
```

If that's true, then it exists, so just show it. If not, load the image into the DOM. Just hide images when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing in your code.

```
  $("#hi1").load('/get_img');
  $("#hi2").load('/get_img');
  $("#hi3").load('/get_img');

  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#h1").load('/get_img').hide().delay(4000).show();
      $("#h2").load('/get_img').hide().delay(4000).show();
      $("#h3").load('/get_img').hide().delay(4000).show();
      }, 0);
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  })
```

So once the dom is ready, it loads the images, and immediately hides it. Then after a `delay(4000)` delay of 4 seconds, it shows the contents.